# Finite union of closed set is closed

Tags: general-topology

I try to proof that Finite union of closed set is closed. Using this definition of closed set:
Closed set it is a set wich contain all its limit points.

So i strart from this:
We have $E_{1},...., E_{n}$ - closed set. Lets see set $$E = \bigcup_{i} E_{i}$$ let $p \in E_{i}$ is  arbitary limit point. Then we know what exists neighborhood of $p$ which contains at least one point of the set different from p. Because we have union then $p\in E$ and p is limit point for $E$

Next thing, I don't quite know what to do.

Comment: these questions are quite basic and have been asked many times on this website. You should check before posting a question which have been asked many times on this website.

Answer (score 1):

It is simpler to use the definition of closed sets as the complements of open sets. Then by de Morgan's laws, the complement of a finite union of closed sets is a finite intersection of open sets, which is open by the definition of a topology.